# Installing Team Foundation Server on a shared database instance

Tags: sql-server, installation, team-foundation-server

Would you use a database instance used for development work to store TFS Data Layer ?
If that's not the case, what kind of separation would you use ?

Setup : we have ONE server for all common dev work. Due to physical constraints, we can't add anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new instance would be a good level of isolation. TFS installs a few databases, in addition to the sharepoint and reporting services databases. I just wouldn't be happy with all of those databases cluttering my primary instance, but that *would* work too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. You're basically confirming my impression.