# Repairing a TFS 2005 install or starting anew

Tags: team-foundation-server

Following : [Installing Team Foundation Server on a shared database instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/45037/installing-team-foundation-server-on-a-shared-database-instance)

We did use a shared database instance setup for TFS 2005, and that was not a good idea, because of the Reporting Service dependency. The reporting instance on the server gives error code 404.

### What works now

- Basic source code control. We're able to check in and out source code.

### What doesn't work :

Everything else, including :

- Opening and creating new team projects.
- Build automation.
- Internal bug tracking.

### Goal setup

- Having a fully working TFS install, and keeping the history.
  1) A full install of TFS 2005 on the same server, but within its own database and reporting instance.
  2) Using another server might be an option, but it's really not prefered
- Downtime should be minimum, my colleagues needs to be able to work on the source

### Readings

I've read [the MSDN page about moving/restoring TFS 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms404860%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), but I'm still unsure about what to do.

Thanks in advance for help